# How to implement transitions between views via a UIPickerView in iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipickerview

I want to implement a custom drop down menu which will allow user to change views in iOS application quickly. I decided to use `UIPickerView` for this purpose. But I didn't find any tutorials on how to change views via a `UIPickerView` so I need some help with this and advice. Code samples will be very helpful.

Comment: @rdelmar I tried to follow this tutorial http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2012/09/uipickerview-tutorial.html and use UINavigationController. But it doesn't work - I have an exceptions.

Comment: Show the code that you tried, and also the exceptions that you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below method is the `UIPickerview` delegate method for row selection.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:
(NSInteger)component    
{
    //in this method hide the views that you don't want to show and show the views that you
    //don't want to hide, when a particular row is selected.

    NSLog(@"row selected----->>%d",row);
}
```